# In-app products doesn't show in the live build

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, itunes

I have added **in-app** purchases to the second version of the app I'm currently working on. It worked perfectly in the sandbox mode. The **new version** of the app released today but my products doesn't show in the iTunes and also when I'm trying to purchase the in-app it shows 0 results. But in the iTunes it shows that the app offers in-app purchases. I don't know the reason for this. Please can anyone help me out here.

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: It's not regarding the code mate. The products doesn't show up in the itunes even though it got approved.

Comment: it takes few days fro approval then only you can see in the app..:)

Comment: it already got approved. The status of the app is 'Ready for Sale' and the status of the product is 'Approved'.

Comment: In-app purchase has also their review period. Can you please check your in app purchase status, it should say "Ready for sale". Anything other than this you need to check e.g. "Developer action needed", Also check You have selected "cleared for sale option"

Comment: The status of the in app purchases is 'Approved'.

Comment: Did you tick the 'Ready for Sale' checkbox for your products in iTunes Connect?

Comment: Yes I have. Strangely one product is available now, and the other one is still not available.

Comment: what happened with this? how did you solve it?